# Software packages for neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am looking for a very **lightweight** neural network package to solve the following problem:

- 2 input units, 4 hidden units, 2 output units
- different activation functions for different connections
- different cost (error) functions for the two output units

Could somebody, perhaps with more experience, please help?

Comment: I'm not sure about the "lightweight" requirement, but you can take a look at the following nice curated list of various ML frameworks, libraries and tools, including the NN ones: https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning. You may also find this collection helpful: http://deeplearning.net/software_links.

Comment: If you are familiar with Python you may consider using pybrain: https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Weka, where you have [MultilayerPerceptron](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html), which is an out-of-the-box neural network classifier. But this is probably not suitable for your problem, so you can use the basic class [NeuralNode](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/neural/NeuralNode.html), which is used by the MultilayerPerceptron to build it's neural network.

If you manage to separate all the needed code in and pack it into your own custom classes, you will end with a very lightweight solution - not counting the JVM needed to run it.

In which programming language or environment do you plan to implement this? If you already use Java, then the JVM will not be an overhead, since you already use it.